# Border Transition Duration only works on mouse over, not on mouse out

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to discover why the border transition duration only works on mouse over. If you hover over the demo, see that the border takes 0.3s to appear, but on moving your mouse it, it disappears instantly.

Why does this happen? Even if applying the transition delay to all elements fails.

```css
#test {
  width: 100%;
  background: lightgreen;
  min-height: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#test:hover {
  border: 5px solid red;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<div id='test'>stuff</div>
```

Comment: Put the `transition` property on `#test` (that handle both over and out)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have not define border by default try to put border property in default also move your transition to default this is the 2nd reason why your transition is not working

```css
#test {
  width: 100%;
  background: lightgreen;
  min-height: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  border: 0 solid red;
}
#test:hover {
  border-width: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id='test'>stuff</div>
```

Comment: and you changed the transition to the non-hover state, this is also important

Answer (score 1):

Normal situation does not require border, so its set 0. then the same thing require transition to happen, otherwise animation will not happen...

```css
#test {
  width: 100%;
  background: lightgreen;
  min-height: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  border: 0px solid red;
}
#test:hover {
  border: 5px solid red;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<div id='test'>stuff</div>
```

Comment: we can then remove it from the hover .. and it's good to add one line of explanation